# How do I create a javax.ws.rs.core.Response in JUnit?

Tags: java, junit, jax-rs, httpresponse

I am trying to use JUnit4 test a utility method that takes a javax.ws.rs.core.Response as an input parameter. The method looks at the Response attributes and takes some action based on the response code. When I just create a response in my test method and submit it using:

```
Response resp = Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(respMessage).build();
ResponseParser.parseResponse(resp);
```

My utility method throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: RESTEASY003290: Entity is not backed by an input stream
    at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.readEntity(BuiltResponse.java:231)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.readEntity(BuiltResponse.java:218)
```

My util class is basically:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status.Family;

public class ResponseParser {

  public static void parseResponse(Response response) {
    String errorResp = "";
    if (!response.getStatusInfo().getFamily().equals(Family.SUCCESSFUL)) {
      int errorCode = response.getStatus();

      errorResp = response.readEntity(String.class);

    }
  }
}
```

How can I create a response that will be properly backed by a stream as expected by resteasy? I looked at quite a few similar questions but they mostly seemed to be centered around testing or mocking an endpoint call. I just want to test my parsing method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mock the Response with some unit testing framework, like Mockito. Then you will be able to declare what to return on each response method call, or even check if a method has been called.

Comment: See my answer below for a code example of how I implemented the mock.

Answer (score 3):

I did end up doing what @albert_nil suggested. Here is the relevant code from my test class.  MessageParseUtil.parseReportResponse(mockResponse); is the utility method that is being tested.

```
  @Test
  public void parse_Report_Response_400_Test() {
    String respMessage = "400 : Validation error occurred. Invalid Parm: employeeID";
    Response mockResponse = buildMockResponse(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, respMessage);

    try {
      MessageParseUtil.parseReportResponse(mockResponse);

      fail("Expected parseReportResponse() to throw error but none thrown.");

    } catch (RestClientException e) {
      Assert.assertEquals("Expected to status code to be 400 but was " + e.getStatusCode() + " instead.", 400, e.getStatusCode());
      Assert.assertEquals("The error message was missing or not correct.", respMessage, e.getErrorMessage().getErrorMessageList().get(0));
    }
  }

  private Response buildMockResponse(Status status, String msgEntity) {
    Response mockResponse = mock(Response.class);
    Mockito.when(mockResponse.readEntity(String.class)).thenReturn(msgEntity);
    Mockito.when(mockResponse.getStatus()).thenReturn(status.getStatusCode());
    Mockito.when(mockResponse.getStatusInfo()).thenReturn(status);

    return mockResponse;
  }
```